# File name match using regular expresssion

Tags: c#, regex

I have below C# code to compare file name using regular expression.

```
private string PPMFileName = "p_p_m";

private string FilePattern = PPMFileName + @"(.*)\.csv"; //File gets appended with date

private Regex regex = new Regex(FilePattern)

if(regex.IsMatch(file.Name))
 //do my stuff
```

It returns true even for file name p_p_m_er_bo_20140324.csv, where as I want it only to return true for file name p_p_m_20140324.csv (Date will keep changing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the regex part to:

```
@"_\d{8}\.csv"
```

So that it will match only one underscore and 8 digits after the file name.

It might also be a good idea to escape the file name in case it contains regex meta chars:

```
private string FilePattern = Regex.Escape(PPMFileName) + @"_\d{8}\.csv";
```

Comment: Awesome. Wasn't aware of Regex.Escape.